# Why is my character tired when she wakes up?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

For some reason whenever I begin playing in my town, my character walks out the door to her house, but then this weird animation plays. She does this arm motion like she's fanning her forehead with her hand while sweat drops fall from her head like she just got done doing a hard day's work, or as if it was hot outside.
Is she tired? Am I doing something wrong? Why does this animation always play when I boot up my game? Does it effect my gameplay at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when your character wears warm clothes in Summer.
iirc if you wear light clothing in winter, you will see your character shiver when leaving the house after start up.

Comment: Ah, that would make sence. I was wearing a blue flannel shirt before. Didn't know that was considered "warm"!

Answer (score -2):

If you haven't played the game for a while you'll get this animation playing. Also if you *time travel* (i.e., changing system time and re-enter the game) you'll also get this animation.

Comment: I play the game everyday and i dont time travel. Sometimes i revisit it on the same day and the animation still plays